# Как найти второй максимум в списке из последовательности чисел?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Можете просто примерно написать как думать, а то вообще идей нет

Comment: В списке нужно найти второй максимум?

Comment: @ E1mir, да именно в списке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно написать функцию:

```
def find_maxes(array, count):
    # копируем список чтобы не изменить старую
    copied_array = array.copy()
    maximums = []
    if count > len(copied_array):
        raise ValueError('Количество не может превышать длину списка')
    for _ in range(count):
        max_val = max(copied_array)  # получаем максимальное значение
        copied_array.remove(copied_array)  # удаляем его из списка
        maximums.append(max_val)  # добавляем в наш ожидаемый результат
    return maximums
```

или же можно поступить хитро

```
def find_maxes(array, count):
    if count > len(array):
        raise ValueError('Количество не может превышать длину списка')
    sorted_array = sorted(array)  # отсортировать список
    # Забрать последние элементы из спика так как они будут максимальными
    return sorted_array[len(array)-count: len(array)]
```

Comment: про удаление максимального числа и нахождение его по новому я даже не догадывался, спасибо что помогли

Comment: Да незачто) Будут вопросы, не стесняйтесь пишите сюда, и вам обязательно кто-то ответит)

Answer (score 2):

```
first_max = int(input())
second_max = int(input())
if first_max < second_max:
    first_max, second_max = second_max, first_max
element = int(input())
while element != 0:
    if element > first_max:
        second_max, first_max = first_max, element
    elif element > second_max:
        second_max = element
    element = int(input())
print(second_max)
```

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуй эффективнее всего будет воспользоваться функцией  [heapq.nlargest()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest):

```
from heapq import nlargest

res = nlargest(2, items)[1]
```